# How to create a searchable componenent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi so I have some data that I want to search and filter through using hooks. I am able to get the initial list loaded but I don't know how to search the array and if the input text matches text in the array then display the array text that matches the input text.  I tried using filter and stuff but am just confused as to how to put it all together. The data I need I can get by using `props.data.map((e) => e.name)`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CharacterCard from "./CharacterCard";
import CharacterList from "./CharacterList";
export default function SearchForm(props) {
  console.log(props.data.map((e) => e.name));
let hi = []
props.data.map((e) => hi.push(e.name))
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const check = () => {
    if(search === ''){
      return <CharacterCard data={props.data} />
    } else if (hi.indexOf(search) === -1 ){
      return <CharacterCard data={props.data} />
    } else {
      return <h1>{I want this to be anything that matches the input bot value}</h1>
    }
  }
  let handleChange =(e) => {
      setSearch(e.target.value)

  }


  return (
    <section className="search-form">
           <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={search} />
    {check()}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you share what `props.data` is?

Comment: ```props.data.map((e) => e.name)``` gives you ``` ["Leanne Graham", "Ervin Howell", "Clementine Bauch", "Patricia Lebsack", "Chelsey Dietrich", "Mrs. Dennis Schulist", "Kurtis Weissnat", "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V", "Glenna Reichert", "Clementina DuBuque"]```

Comment: and what would you like to do with the search? it's not  clear what you mean by "just return an `<h1>{props.data}</h1>` of just what I type in the input box".

Comment: I want to search the array and if the input text matches text in the array display the array text that matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to modify your `check` function. This example will render a list of all names that have a partial match in the beginning of the name:

```js
  const check = () => {
    // get array of all names in `props.data`
    const names = props.data.map(e => e.name);

    // this will filter out any names that do not start with the content of `search`
    // leaving us with an array of matching names
    const searchMatches = names.filter(name => name.startsWith(search));

    // do something with the results `searchMatches`
    // (this example returns a list of names)
    return <ul>{searchMatches.map(name => <li key={name}>{name}</li><ul>
  })
```